# Xcode Mac sfml Library not found

Tags: xcode, sfml

So I tried to run Sfml app on Xcode, I successfully got Build Succeed. But then this showed up:\

`dyld[99058]: Library not loaded: @rpath/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system Referenced from: <844C7D0D-A6F9-3F68-9230-AA99D487BD59> /Users/mba/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/111-gnemsuvsngslpvehktfdebigdetj/Build/Products/Debug/111.app/Contents/MacOS/111 Reason: tried: '/Users/mba/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/111-gnemsuvsngslpvehktfdebigdetj/Build/Products/Debug/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file), '/Users/mba/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/111-gnemsuvsngslpvehktfdebigdetj/Build/Products/Debug/111.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file), '/Users/mba/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/111-gnemsuvsngslpvehktfdebigdetj/Build/Products/Debug/111.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file)`

I have NO idea what this is and how to solve. I downloaded Sfml from Sfml site and this is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please give me solution for this. Thanks in advance.

I dunno what to do with this thing. If it shows up some green circle I would be so happy.